# Apache wicket + google maps API

Tags: apache, google-maps, wicket

is there a stable api for integrating Wicket 7 with the latest version of google maps api? (Aside from using javascript).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/gmap3-parent

Docu: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Gmap3

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-gmap3</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0-M5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you martin!